# Using WebApi and structure map dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, structuremap

Although there are so many question on stack overflow which tends similar to my this question but no one is resolving my problem

I was using an MVC4 internet application wherein i had few MVC controller and for dependency injection i was using `Structure map`. Although dependency injection works fine with MVC controller but when i added an WebApi controller in the same MVC internet application and using the same parameter in constructor of WebApi controller as what i am using in MVC controller but dependency injection is not working with WebApi controller, although if i don't use dependency injection for WebApi controller(parameterless constructor), then it works fine, but for WebApi dependency injection(parameterized constructor) it is throwing an error `No parameter less constructor is found`.

Conclusion depedencies are not being injected for WebApi Controller in Internet(MVC application).

Few articles suggested to use `DependencyResolver.SetResolver()`. i used but did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why WebApi controller were not working is as following:

**Since MVC Controller uses different DependenyResolver instance that is the part of System.Web.MVC .dll and within the System.Web.MVC namespace**

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver(v=vs.98).aspx**

**Where as Api Controllers uses DependencyResolver instance that is part of System.Web.Http.**

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver(v=vs.108).aspx**

Answer (score 1):

MVC and WebAPI controllers have a different way of setting their dependency resolver. This is how I set my dependency resolver for Unity:

```
public void ConfigureForMvc4()
{
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
        new UnityMvc4.UnityDependencyResolver(Container));
}

public void ConfigureForWebApi()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new UnityWebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(Container);
}
```

Comment: Nou you haven't. You're talking about `DependencyResolver.SetResolver`, which is used for MVC controllers. Web API controllers use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`.

Comment: Oh I tried to use this
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new UnityWebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(Container);
but in my case what i would write my SmDependencyResolve deriver form IDependcencyResolver of system.web.mvc where Global configuration dependency resolver is form system.web.http IDependency resolver

Comment: Is there any seperate nuget for Structure map for MVC and structure map for WebApi controller

Comment: I know the question is old but, in the spirit of currency, I came across this one for WebApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.WebApi2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Dependency Injection files for WebApi

Install NuGet StructureMap.WebApi2 and in the App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs file, call StructuremapWebApi.Start();

Refer: https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/setting-up-dependency-injection-in-web-api-with-structuremap/